# How do you draw a motor using circuitkz?

Tags: circuitikz

How do you add a motor to this circuit diagram? I could do most of this circuit except the motor part. Below is what I am trying to copy in `LaTeX` vs my code. The last line in `Circuitikz` produces an error.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages] \draw (0,3) to[american voltage source, l=$V_0$] (0,0)
(0,3) to[resistor, l=$R_{\omega}$] (3,3)
(3,3) to[resistor, l=$R_{\omega}$] (6,3)
(6,3) to[inductor, l=$L_a$] (8,3)
(8,3) to[Motor, l=20 $\Omega$] (8,0) %gives an error
(8,0)--(0,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: yup just added the package

Comment: Looks like you're looking for `elmech` type node. Read section 4.17 of circuitikz manual

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
\draw   (0,0)   to[Telmech=M, n=motor] (0,3)
                to[R,a=$R_{\omega}$] ++ (-2,0)
                to[R,a=$R_{\omega}$] ++ (-2,0)
                to[V=$V_0$]          ++ (0,-3)
                -- (0,0);
\node[right] at (motor.east) {20 $\Omega$}; % what designate this label? 
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is not entirely clear, what designate `20 $\Omega$`. In case that this is value of inner resistance, than is better write it as `\qty{20}{\ohm}` and load `circuitikz` with option `siunitx`.